# Call a particular function (function pointer) on an object

Tags: c++

If I have a function pointer

```
MyFunctionPointer myFunctionPointer;
```

I can pass it parameters like:

```
myFunctionPointer(1,2);
```

I am looking to do something similar, but call a particular function on an object. I currently have something like this:

```
if(case1)
  myObject.Case1();
else if(case2)
  myObject.Case2();
```

Instead, is there any way to do something like:

```
  myObject.myFunctionPointer();
```

?

Thanks,

David

Comment: `boost::bind` has handy wrappers for doing this.

Comment: Nice link on the topic: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a function pointer as a member function of a class then yes you can assign your function to that member function and then later call the function.

so if you declare a function pointer in your class

```
int (*foo)(int) = NULL; // takes int arg, returns int
```

once you assign the method to a function you can call it as you desire:

```
myObject.foo(42);
```

e.g.

```
class myfoo
{
public:
    int (*foo)(int);
};

int myfoofunc(int n)
{
    return n/2;
}

...

myfoo f;
f.foo = myfoofunc;
cout << f.foo(2) << endl; // would output 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this: http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html. Maybe it helps you?

Quoted:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    double One( long inVal );
    double Two( long inVal );
};

int main()
{
    double (Foo::*funcPtr)( long ) = &Foo::One;
    Foo aFoo;
    double result =(aFoo.*funcPtr)( 2 ); 
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, the quoted link's main function had "void" as return type and still returned zero. See the original link and change return type to "int". That should help. Thanks for paying attention. :)

Answer (score 1):

If both member functions have the same signature you might declare a member function pointer

```
return_type (CMyClass::*variable)(paramtype1, paramtype2) = &CMyClass::Case1;
```

and call it like

```
return_type ret = (myObject.*variable)(param1, param2);
```

Comment: See [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) for more information.